# Best way to constantly draw large numbers of bitmaps in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, bitmap

I am stumped by this very simple problem. I am making a tile-based game engine and need to be able to allow a user to edit the map using a WPF User Interface. Naively, I had assumed that I could simply constantly update a good old fashioned "buffered" System.Drawing.Graphics.Bitmap using Graphics.FromImage. I would draw onto the bitmap the tiles that make up the map, and then blit the buffer Bitmap to the screen. However, from my thorough research I now believe that it isn't that easy at all.

Rather than bore you with what I've found out so far (that either doesn't work, or is incredibly slow), may I ask very simply, what is the best way for continuously drawing large numbers of bitmaps efficiently via a WPF UI?

I will accept such suggestions as "go back to Windows Forms". If that's the case, then I am going to be very dissapointed with WPF!

Comment: Can you post the code you are currently using to load the images?

Answer (score 3):

The WriteableBitmap class is a high-performance WPF-compatible bitmap that allows direct access to its bits. [This MSDN documentation page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap.aspx) contains a fairly thorough example of using it.

Answer (score 0):

Freezable can make a big difference to performance when dealing with Bitmaps, you can then also load the buffer using a background thread to stop the UI locking up.

This [tutorial](http://zorder.wordpress.com/2008/12/03/bitmapimage-loading-performace-and-freeze/) covers the basics